# Evaluation of this infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Given the following infinite series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n)^{p}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{p}}$

Find the summation of this series?

**My approach:**

The above series expands to:

Sum = $(\frac{1}{1^p}-\frac{1}{2^p}) +(\frac{1}{2^p}-\frac{1}{3^p}) + (\frac{1}{3^p}-\frac{1}{4^p})+ (\frac{1}{4^p}-\frac{1}{5^p}).... (\frac{1}{(\infty)^p}-\frac{1}{(\infty+2)^p})$

Since, from second term onward, all neighboring terms cancel each other out all the 'middle' terms will cancel each other out. Thus it will evaluate to:

Sum = $(\frac{1}{1^p} - \frac{1}{(\infty+2)^p})$

As, for any finite real/complex value of: $p$ $(\infty+2)^p = \infty$. Thus,

Sum = $(\frac{1}{1^p} - \frac{1}{\infty})$.

As, $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$. Thus:

Sum = $\frac{1}{1^p}$. (for any finite value of $p$).

**Query**: Is the above argument correct and can we can replace the series with $\frac{1}{1^p}$ in any equation or not?

Comment: You're throwing around $\infty$ like it's an actual number...

Comment: No it is not sound. Fortunately there is a very simple way to make it rigorous.

Comment: @Did I was wondering if the method below (in the answer) is what you had in mind when you said that there is a simple way to make it rigorous?

Comment: It is. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, although the symbol $\infty$ can be handled in a different way. For example, call

$$
S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^p} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^p}
$$

You showed that

$$
S_N = 1 - \frac{1}{(N + 1)^p}
$$

The sum you are interested in is

$$
S = \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = 1
$$

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, when we say $S = \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = 1$ instead of $\frac{1}{1^p}$ we essentially imply that as $\lim_{N \to \infty} then \frac{1}{(N + 1)^p} \to 0$. Thus, it is never exactly 0 but goes asymptotically to 0. Now, here is what I am struggling with. (1) If I remember correctly, $.99999...$ with infinite digits is considered equal to 1. Why can't we have the same argument for this case?

Comment: (2) In any equation, do we replace the series, with $S = \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = 1$ as the sum instead of 1 (as I thought) ?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 You can replace the series as 1, as it converges to 1. You can see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263507/what-do-convergence-and-divergence-mean-and-why-do-they-matter) other post, maybe it will help you